# How can I automate sending a form and saving the result web page?

Tags: windows, web, extract

I have a site where on the page is text input field and submit button.

I need to put numbers 1 to 100 in that text field and save the resulting page after the submit button has been clicked. So I need to have 100 pages downloaded.

In these downloaded pages I will look for the information I need.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If the website is submitting the form's data using `GET`, when you click on submit, you should see the submitted data on your browser's address bar. Something like:

```
http://www.somesite.com/someform?numbers=1
```

If that is the case, you can run the command in a for loop:

1. Install [wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).
2. Modify (change the paths according to your needs) and run this command:

   ```
   FOR /L %i IN (1,1,100) DO ("C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" --output-document "C:\Users\SomeUserName\SomeDir\%i.html" http://www.somesite.com/someform?numbers=%i)
   ```

EXPLANATION:

The for loop has this format: `(start,step,end)`. So, the loop above will go through all the numbers from 1 to 100 in increments of 1. At each iteration, it will set the value of variable `%i` to the current number.

Wget will download a webpage from a given URL. Using the address from the previous step, it will replace the number in `numbers=1` with each of the numbers from 1 to 100, download the corresponding webpage and save it as "number".html in the directory `C:\Users\SomeUserName\SomeDir\%i.html`.

If you need more help, please post the URL of the website form you will be using.

Comment: Thank you, but the website is using POST not the GET. So do you have another solution?

Comment: @Matop79, Can you give us the URL?

Comment: http://nahlizenidokn.cuzk.cz/VyberBudovu.aspx?typ=Stavba   "Vyhledat" is a Submit button and "Číslo stavby" is a text field where the number goes. And as the "Název/kód obce:" choose Ostrava

Comment: @Matop79, sorry, no ideas...